# About publishing proofs and some interesting tricks about subject at concern

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Can we publish interesting proofs and helpful tricks on XYZ.stackexchange.com  which we know? How do we do it. How to do it correctly? How to stop it from getting downvotes based on it "not being a question" ? Can we make a question which will be the compilation of useful things like "XYZ tricks"? It will be socially helpful.

How do you get such questions protected?

> Please don't downvote this question, I'm not able to delete the question and downvoting it reduces my reputation.

Comment: The right place to ask is... math.meta.stackexchange.com - they would know best what is and isn't allowed on their site. Asking here, which is used for all Stack Exchange sites wouldn't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks . I am deleting this question, and posting it there.

Comment: @neonpokharkar Unfortunately you can't delete it here now. I don't believe it's completely unuseful now.

Comment: @user0042 OK . Should i atleast generalise it then?

Comment: Might improve that Q&A, yes.

Comment: The [original version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/300984/1) -which was about Mathematics - is now posted on Mathematics Meta: [About publishing proofs and math tricks](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we publish interesting proofs and math tricks on math.stackexchange which we know?

I'm pretty sure you can.
But well, it depends on their policies for well asked questions and answers. How these *publishings* are presented needs to follow the specific site's model to be well received.

In general you should post both, a question and an answer in the required best quality to be well received by a specific site's community.

> How do you get such questions protected.

Questions can be protected by trusted users with a minimum of 15.000 points of reputation. Read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

---

If you need a more detailed answer, please ask at [Meta Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How to get such questions protected, or , when do they get protected?

Comment: @neonpokharkar I answered that point as well now.